# How can I listen to events on other applications?

Tags: javascript, electron

Building an electron app. Trying to see if I can embed some sort of event listener into other applications, then based on that return a console message. An example is being able to track if I'm opening a new tab on chrome and return a message saying "Just opened a new tab."

Comment: For security reasons you can not track such activities from chrome or any other application/website. The only exception to this would be chrome extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it unfortunately is not yet possible, with JavaScript, to determine if the user has opened a new tab in google chrome or other browsers. The only thing you could do to see this would be to check from the input system (e.g. keys pressed), but the user would probably press the *new tab* button in the browser!